# Kotlin Android studio : Non clickable calendar-view

Tags: android, kotlin

i have a basic calendar view for my home screen of app

Goal: Display todays date but don't allow the user to click any other date

Problem: Using non-clickable or clickable = false doesnt work.

How do i make a calendar view in XML or kt non clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
enabled = false
```

And if that doesn't work try implementing the empty click event listener.